# Sqlalchemy with postgres. Try to get 'DISTINCT ON' instead of 'DISTINCT'

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, distinct

I need to generate query like this:

```
SELECT **DISTINCT ON** (article.code) article.code, article.title
```

First I try to make it via ORM distinct method and send it a list with fields. But it wont work. Second, I try to make it via sqlalchemy.sql.select - and it also generate sql query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT article.code, article.title
```

I Need `SELECT **DISTINCT ON** (article.code)`...

I look at source code and found in `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.PGCompiler.get_select_precolumns` code for generating constructions like: 'DISTINCT ON'
But this method do not called. Instead of this called another method - `sqlalchemy.sql.compiler.get_select_precolumns` - it hasn't code for generating `DISTINCT ON` only for `DISTINCT` Maybe I should configure my session to called properly method?

Answer (score 4):

[This bug report](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2142) suggests that `DISTINCT ON` works correctly in SQLAlchemy 0.7+. I think an upgrade is in order, unless you've uncovered a bug in 0.7.

Workarounds . . .

- Volunteer to help get the 0.7 package
  ready for Ubuntu.
- [Download](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/download.html) and install from
  source.
- Rewrite queries to avoid `DISTINCT
  ON`. I'm not sure whether that's
  possible in the most general case.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 hasn't 0.7 version in repo :(

Comment: You can use `pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade`. Using `pip` makes you independent on your system's packaging, where are usually outdated/not-so-on-edge versions of Python libraries :-)