# How to execute SELECT DISTINCT ON query using SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a requirement to display spend estimation for last 30 days.  SpendEstimation is calculated multiple times a day. This can be achieved using simple SQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date) date(time) AS date, resource_id , time
FROM spend_estimation
WHERE
  resource_id = '<id>'
  and time > now() - interval '30 days'
ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC;
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to be able to do the same using SQLAlchemy. It always creates select distinct on all columns. Generated query does not contain `distinct on`.

```py
query = session.query(
    func.date(SpendEstimation.time).label('date'),
    SpendEstimation.resource_id,
    SpendEstimation.time
).distinct(
    'date'
).order_by(
    'date',
    SpendEstimation.time
)
```

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    date(time) AS date,
    resource_id,
    time 
FROM spend
ORDER BY date, time
```

It is missing `ON (date)` bit. If I user `query.group_by` - then SQLAlchemy adds `distinct on`. Though I can't think of solution for given problem using group by.

---

Tried using function in distinct part and order by part as well.

```py
query = session.query(
    func.date(SpendEstimation.time).label('date'),
    SpendEstimation.resource_id,
    SpendEstimation.time
).distinct(
    func.date(SpendEstimation.time).label('date')
).order_by(
    func.date(SpendEstimation.time).label('date'),
    SpendEstimation.time
)
```

Which resulted in this SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       date(time) AS date,
       resource_id,
       time,
       date(time) AS date # only difference
FROM spend
ORDER BY date, time
```

Which is still missing `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: what dbms are you using? AFAIK SQLAlchemy supports DISTINCT ON only on specific dialects

Comment: Re: @architectonic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223174/returning-distinct-rows-in-sqlalchemy-with-sqlite - see first answer

Comment: Re @architectonic thats very good question - I'm using postgresql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SqlAlchemy version might be the culprit.

[Sqlalchemy with postgres. Try to get 'DISTINCT ON' instead of 'DISTINCT'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175657/sqlalchemy-with-postgres-try-to-get-distinct-on-instead-of-distinct)

Links to this bug report:
https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/2142

A fix wasn't backported to 0.6, looks like it was fixed in 0.7.

Comment: Have to confess that I did not test the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question: have you tried distinct on `SpendEstimation.date` instead of `'date'`?

EDIT: It just struck me that you're trying to use the named column from the `SELECT`. SQLAlchemy is not that smart. Try passing in the `func` expression into the `distinct()` call.

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggestion, `SpendEstimation.date` column does not exist, it is calculated from spend_time. Maybe it is possible to add "virtual_column" to the model, not sure.

I've tried passing `func` to distinct and it didn't change query in expected way.

Comment: OK. Another stupid question: what version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: Also, what is the updated Python code using the `func` approach? Have you tried wrapping `'date'` in a `text()`?